# Access fields of an aliased type in Scala

Tags: scala

I'd like to alias a type:

```
 type T = Int
```

Is there a way that I could do this afterwards?

```
 T.MaxValue
```

Comment: `MaxValue` is a method defined in _object_ `Int`, it has nothing to do with _type_ `Int`.

Comment: You mean `val T = Int`.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112637/access-to-a-types-companion-object), and its answer, might be of some help.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's not a way to do this.  When you say `Int.MaxValue`, you're accessing a static field of the Int object:

```
object Int extends AnyValCompanion {
...
    final val MaxValue = java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE
...
}
```

When you bind a type with `type T = Int`, you're only inheriting the type, so you don't get the object as well.  You can, however, do the following:

```
scala> val t = Int
t: Int.type = object scala.Int

scala> t.MaxValue
res2: Int = 2147483647
```

Comment: Or `val T = Int`. And you can have both `val T` and `type T` at once.